# Get Text and replace the word with the selected text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, replace, str-replace

I want to replace a word from the text taken by css selector like

`company_name  = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("body > company.b1").text`

let's it took the text like this "GBH Global"

`description  = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("body > p.b1").text`

let's it took the text like this "This is companyname we are based in london"

and I want to do this and replace the company name with GBH Global like "This is GBH Global we are based in london"

```
company_description  = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("body > p.b1 > input") 
company_description.send_keys(description)
```

I want to send like this ""This is GBH Global we are based in london" using selenium and python

I have this text "This is companyname we are based in london" and I can change its format for the code to work it properly...

Comment: Try use replace the string with your expected string `description=description.replace('companyname','GBH Global')`

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the *text* extracted by the line of code:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("body > company.b1").text
```

i.e. **GBH Global** would be a variable. In that case you can replace the text **companyname** as follows:

```
company_name  = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("body > company.b1").text
description  = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("body > p.b1").text
text_to_replace = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("body > company.b1").text.split()[2]
print(description.replace(text_to_replace, "{}".format(company_name)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work

```
company_name  = "GBH Global"
description  = "This is companyname we are based in london"
company_description = description.replace("companyname", company_name)
```